# How to get date from gRPC server using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http2, grpc

I found out that the Chrome can use HTTP2.0 by http://www.chromium.org/spdy/http2.
But how can I get data from a gRPC server using chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers are [not currently supported](http://www.grpc.io/faq/). gRPC requires trailer support, which is not generally available on browsers.